# PHP / LARAVEL: Need to show all taxes exept key=0

Tags: php, laravel

I am using an open source billing program that I found on the web. I have managed to modify several elements, however I have serious problems with taxes.

The challenge is here, at least for me;

In my country we use three taxes; 15%, 18% and 0% (which would be an exempt product). I need my invoice to always list 15% and 18% (no matter if any of them are not invoiced, because currently it only shows the tax that has been invoiced), but i also need the tax with label '0%' to be omitted.

**It currently does this:**

subtotal ------------------ L. 537.00
subtotal taxed (15%) - L. 297.00
subtotal taxed (18%) - L. 0.00
exempt ------------------- L. 240.00
15% ------------------ (+) L. 44.55
0% -------------------- (+) L.0.00 -> **I need this to go away**
Discounts (0%) ----- (-) L. 0.00
Total ----------------------- L. 581.55

**and I need it to be something like this:**

subtotal ----------------- L. 537.00 
subtotal taxed(15%) - L. 297.00
subtotal taxed(18%) - L. 0.00
exempt ------------------ L. 240.00
15% ----------------- (+) L. 44.55
18% ----------------- (+) L. 0.00 -->**included even if it has not been invoiced**
Discounts (0%) ---- (-) L. 0.00
Total ---------------------- L. 581.55

The actual code goes like this:

```
<!-- Taxes -->
    @foreach($receipt_details->taxes as $k => $v)
        <tr>
            <th style="width:70%">{{$k}}</th>
            <td class="text-right">{{$v}}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
```

Comment: can you give the github repo of that opensource billing program...

Comment: Can you show us how does `$receipt_details->taxes` array looks like ? Then I can help you modify it in the way you need it before entering foreach loop

Comment: @Osta Down what i found on `App\Utils\TransactionUtil.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a simple approach to handle this request. What you can do is:

```
@foreach($receipt_details->taxes as $k => $v)
    @if($k == "0%")
       pass;
    @else
       <tr>
          <th style="width:70%">{{$k}}</th>
          <td class="text-right">{{$v}}</td>
       </tr>
@endforeach
```

assuming you're getting `18%` tax value in your `$receipt_details->taxes` array. You can easily handle it in the above code. If you can show the code for `$receipt_details->taxes` then I can handle it better for handling `18%` tax.

Comment: the code didn´t work out, I got an error.  Since yesterday I am trying to locate the code for this array `$receipt_details->taxes`, and i found this file `app\Utils\TransactionUtil.php` where i found this:

Comment: Down what i found on `App\Utils\TransactionUtil.php`

Comment: Please can you dump your array for `$receipt_details`

Comment: Just to inform you that this code did work, the only error was the `{` that was left over there, until last night I could notice it, so sorry for that.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out mistake. Fixed it in answer.